# checking the file sizes not passing test cases

Tags: c#, hash

I am comparing two excel files and for my current test - I have two files exactly the same each containing one column and 5 rows. When I check if they are equal or not, it fails and says that one of the files has added items to it.

Not sure if I am checking something the wrong way:

```
bool areEqual = false;
if (fileB.excelRows.Count() == fileA.excelRows.Count())
{
    int i = 0;
    while ((i < fileB.excelRows.Count()) && (fileB.excelRows[i] == fileA.excelRows[i]))
    {
        i += 1;
    }
    if (i == fileB.excelRows.Count())
    {
        areEqual = true;
    }
}
if (areEqual)
    MessageBox.Show("The files are the same");
else
{
    ....
}
```

Comment: Can you give us more information about the class/type of excelRows?

Comment: @jmstoker i went ahead and added the classes above.

Comment: @GrantWinney cuz he is currently unavailable and i need to get this done as soon as possible :) Plus he didn't provide the compare method - that was on my own

Comment: @Masriyah it's obviously that one of the rows are not equal. You should try debugging step by step to see the values of both rows in each loop.

Comment: @KingKing the first if statement is right and then steps in to the while statement but doesn't increase i and then the inner if statement  i and the fileB count are not the same

Comment: @KingKing - i am trying to follow this example: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307020 the Compare Two Hash Values section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `SequenceEqual` method on excelRows[i].rowHash.

Instead of:

```
while ((i < fileB.excelRows.Count()) && (fileB.excelRows[i] == fileA.excelRows[i]))
```

Change it to:

```
while ((i < fileB.excelRows.Count()) && 
    (fileB.excelRows[i].rowHash.SequenceEqual(fileA.excelRows[i].rowHash)))
```

Comment: Is this targeted to check just the three item?

Comment: Yes, but you can apply it to your algorithm.  In this condition `fileB.excelRows[i] == fileA.excelRows[i]` you are comparing ExcelRow classes.  You need to be comparing the rowHash of each class which can be done by using `SequenceEqual`.

Comment: After testing more of your code, it appears your algorithm is correct for the comparison.  Are you running the Calculatehash() on each row?

Comment: i just added my reading method to show the use of Calculatehash(). I really appreciate your help

Comment: I'm not familiar with ExcelQueryFactory() what is that from?

Comment: it is because i am using linq for the two files and i am using it for selecting the columns - linq to excel use so i can use columns without specific headers

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36290/discussion-between-jmstoker-and-masriyah)

Comment: I was able to figure it out, I'll amend my answer.

Comment: sorry for the delay my laptop went out of charge and forgot my battery - i will try it out now